# Practical examples of use for Clojure's some-> macro

Tags: clojure

Clojure 1.5 adds new threading macros, including:

- `some->`
- `some->>`

The changelog has this contrived example to illustrate how `some->` works:

```
user=> (defn die [x] (assert false))
#'user/die
user=> (-> 1 inc range next next next die)
AssertionError Assert failed: false  user/die (NO_SOURCE_FILE:65)
user=> (some-> 1 inc range next next next die)
nil
```

Chatting with other programmers, we found it difficult to think of a good, practical example for `some->`. When have you used `some->` to solve a real-world problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`some->` can be used to "auto-guard" a threaded series of processing steps where some part in the chain (especially in the middle) might return `nil` which would cause a logic failure further down the chain.

Particular examples could include threading clojure functions together with java interop where you would need to guard against null pointer exceptions.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Java interop. This seems like a perfect use for `some->`

Answer (score 6):

A GitHub code search turns up quite a few [examples](https://github.com/search?q=some-%3E%20extension:.clj&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Answer (score 2):

The [clojuredocs.org page on some->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-%3E) has some `some->` examples*:

```lisp
(-> {:a 1} :b inc)
;; NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:942)

(some-> {:a 1} :b inc)
;; nil
```

* pun intended